# Limit the number of tasks in dispatch_queue_create in swift

Tags: swift

I would like to limit number of tasks run in a `dispatch_queue_t` and ignore all tasks if it reaches the limit, how can I achieve this in swift language, I could not find any information about it?

Comment: Do you really want to ignore all tasks after that limit, or just queue them and have them wait until one of the earlier tasks finish? E.g. queue 10 tasks but only have 3 running at any given time. That's a more common pattern...

Answer (score 0):

Apple already did most of the work for you in `NSOperationQueue`. You only need to modify it slightly to suit your needs:

```
class MyOperationQueue: NSOperationQueue {
    override func addOperationWithBlock(block: () -> Void) {
        if self.operationCount < self.maxConcurrentOperationCount {
            super.addOperationWithBlock(block)
        }
    }
}

let queue = MyOperationQueue()
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 2

queue.addOperationWithBlock {
    print("Task 1")
    sleep(5)
}

queue.addOperationWithBlock {
    print("Task 2")
    sleep(5)
}

queue.addOperationWithBlock {
    // This will be ignored
    print("Task 3")
    sleep(5)
}

queue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
```